# What's the name of this letter?

Tags: mathematics, symbols, alphabet

I came upon this letter when reading a book, I couldn't find its name on the internet, you can imagine how hard it is to search about it.

What is the name of the letter that follows "sample space"?

[image]

I know it's not really an English question, but I think this site is best fit for the question than say, the mathematics site.

Comment: It's also used in the popular Finnish licorice brand, "Sisu" or "Guts": http://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisu_%28pastilli%29 Note the lowercase s in the same font--looks like an f.

Comment: And of course a lowercase s at the end of a word looks more like a modern s ...

Comment: GraphicsDesign.SE does font identifications, providing you check Dextify-like sites first. :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's an *S* written in a [fraktur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) font used by mathematicians. This one is easy to find out using [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).